# Java Package Class Not Found

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Eclipse info:
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Build id: 20100218-1602
JavaFx2.2
jdk1.8.0_05

I'm developing a desktop java app using JavaFx and Eclipse.  I do this

```
ObservableList<String>addressList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(addressListArray);
    lv_property_list.setItems(addressList);
```

to link my data(addressList) with the list view(lv_property_list).  All is well there.  But when I try to customize my list view cells by doing this

```
lv_property_list.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<String>, 
    ListCell<String>>() {
         @Override 
         public ListCell<String> call(ListView<String> list) {
            return new ColorRectCell();
         }
     }
);
```

and adding the inner ColorRectCell Class

```
class ColorRectCell extends ListCell<String> {
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 20);
    if (item != null) {
        rect.setFill(Color.web(item));
        setGraphic(rect);
    }
}
```

I start getting this error:

> The type java.util.function.Function cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

If I drill down into the linked library (JDK1.8.0_05) in my Package Explorer and find the java.util.function package I can see that Function.class is there...but when I double click it to open, I get an error dialog and these messages in the error log:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 2 2014-04-24 20:09:54.234 !MESSAGE
>   Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in:
>   "org.eclipse.jdt.ui". !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:889)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:677)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider$1.run(ASTProvider.java:544)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.createAST(ASTProvider.java:537)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.getAST(ASTProvider.java:478)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider.getAST(SharedASTProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor$3.run(ClassFileEditor.java:683)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jdt.ui 4 0 2014-04-24 20:09:54.234 !MESSAGE Error
>   in JDT Core during AST creation !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.internalCreateAST(ASTParser.java:889)
>     at org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser.createAST(ASTParser.java:677)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider$1.run(ASTProvider.java:544)
>     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)  at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.createAST(ASTProvider.java:537)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ASTProvider.getAST(ASTProvider.java:478)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.ui.SharedASTProvider.getAST(SharedASTProvider.java:126)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.ClassFileEditor$3.run(ClassFileEditor.java:683)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-04-24 20:09:54.285 !MESSAGE An
>   unexpected exception was thrown. !STACK 0
>   java.lang.NullPointerException ....
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-04-24 20:09:54.291 !MESSAGE Unable to
>   create editor ID org.eclipse.jdt.ui.ClassFileEditor: An unexpected
>   exception was thrown. !STACK 0 java.lang.NullPointerException ....
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 2 2 2014-04-24 20:09:54.300 !MESSAGE Ignored
>   attempt to add saveable that was already registered !STACK 0
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: unknown saveable: 
>   ....
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 4 2 2014-04-24 20:09:54.310 !MESSAGE Problems
>   occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface". !STACK
>   0 java.lang.NullPointerException ....

I've tried removing this library from the build path and going back to JDK1.6 or whatever the last one was, but it seems to make no difference.

Also, directly importing java.util.function.Function fails as the class can't be located by eclipse.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

Scott

Comment: Something's messed up with the project setup. One instant red flag is: "JavaFx2.2 jdk1.8.0_05"; JDK 1.8.0 comes with JavaFX 8 already installed (and on the classpath), so it's not clear how you have JavaFX 2.2 there. Check your project setup is using JDK 1.8.0_05, and remove any references to external jfxrt.jar libraries. Additionally, make sure your compiler compliance level (under the Project properties, Java Compiler) is set to 1.8.

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the external jfxrt.jar in the build path.  I also went to change the java compiler compliance level, but the list only goes up to 1.6.

Comment: Your eclipse looks out of date, I guess (not an eclipse expert). Install the latest version, then use [this patch](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/Eclipse_Java_8_Support_For_Kepler). Make sure the Java 8 runtime is present under Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs.

Comment: Updating Eclipse, downloading the patch, and checking my project setup fixed my problem.  Thanks so much James_D!